# Вызов функции по её строковому имени

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как выполнить функцию если ее имя содержится в переменной типа `string`?

Comment: eval() попробуйте

Comment: `globals(переменная)()` или типа того

Comment: тип str а не string

Answer (score 8):

Самый безопасный способ это собрать словарь функций:

```
def func1(text):
    return text

def func2():
    return ""

functions = {'func1':func1, 'func2':func2}
```

Соответственно вызов будет `functions['ваша строка']()`

**Избегайте использования `eval()` всегда когда это возможно, и в карйнем случае используйте `ast.literal_eval()`**

Comment: спасибо. как по мне этот вариант более эфективен и работает. так как для моего кода для телеграма, где задания приходят в виде текста в ключе зарезервированных команд

Answer (score 4):

Зная имя функции можно получить соответствующий объект функции в заданном пространстве имён.

Если имя это глобальная функция в текущем модуле:

```
f = globals()["имя"]
```

Затем самый обычный вызов:  `f(a, b, c)`

Если функция из другого модуля, или это метод класса, объекта, итд то достать функцию можно используя `getattr()`:

```
f = getattr(module, "имя")
```

Не используйте `eval()`, `exec()` без необходимости: это не эффективно и может быть не безопасно (если строка из недоверенного ввода).

Comment: пишите не использовать `exec` а сами рекомендуете `f = globals("имя")`, так вот `exec` это обертка над `globals`

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч нет, globals() словарь глобальных переменных в модуле и exec() функция, которая произвольный код выполняет — это не одно и то же.

Comment: Ну так а каким образом то она его выполняет ? с помощью `globals`, эта функция оперирует глобальным и локальным пространствами имен, там еще и 3 объект есть, не помню какой

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч нет. Покажите как вы "import os" с помощью globals() словаря сделаете.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч если вы не понимаете разницу между словарём и функцией которая **произвольный** Питон код может выполнить,  задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Я то как раз понимаю. Последний раз напишу, она этот код через `globals` выполняет, или в документации врут ? ) Негодяи ...

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч пропробуйте `exec("import os", {}, {})` а теперь попробуйте повторить через `globals()` (если вы думаете, что exec() выполняет питон код через `globals()`, то продемонстрируйте как именно globals() по-вашему здесь поможет exec() реализовать). В документации globals это *имя параметра*. `os.remove(filename)` принимает строку, это не значит, что строки умеют файлы удалять, только потому что функция, которая удаляет файлы, может принимать аргумент строку). Можно передать в exec() словарь возвращаемый globals() функцией, это не значит, что этот словарь умеет всё что exec() делает.

Comment: Я не где и не писал что она прям все через globals выполняет, я написал, что globals входит в объекты над которыми она является оберткой.

Comment: К чему ваш первый комментарий тогда? Если я напишу, что не делайте `import shutil; shutil.rmtree('/')`, а потом порекомендую использование строк, то к чему после этого писать что-то вроде «пишите не использовать `shutil.rmtree`, а сами рекомендуете "использование строк" так вот shutil.rmtree это обертка на строками» (аналогия: `exec()` функция может принимать в качестве аргумента словарь, возвращаемый `globals()`. `shutil.rmtree()` функция может принимать в качестве аргумента строку)

Comment: Ну это вы уже иронизируете )

Answer (score 2):

Можно поступить так:

```
In [1]: def example(value):
   ...:     return value ** 2
   ...:

In [2]: func_name = 'example'

In [3]: eval(func_name)(10)
Out[3]: 100
```

Подробнее про `eval()` можно [почитать тут](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться за что минус? Решение полностью рабочее.

Comment: Да хз - я уже и отвечать перестал из-за єтого ))
Лови от меня пару плюсов ))

Comment: Скорее всего, людям не нравится рекомендация использования eval, так как он небезопасен (о чем говорится в более заплюсованных ответах)

Comment: @Rabter никакой рекомендации тут нет, просто один из вариантов.

Answer (score 1):

`exec` использует текущие глобальные и локальные пространства имён для выполнения кода:

```
exec('print(123)') 
# 123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A:
    def executor(self, fn_name):
        getattr(self, fn_name)()

def do_something(self):
    print('done')

a = A()
a.executor('do_something')
```

Всегда старайтесь избегать потенциальную уязвимость в виде выполнения произвольного кода. Ею могут воспользоваться. В данном примере происходит поиск метода по имени и его дальнейший вызов.